# Request has been rejected because of queue limit

Tags: parity, parity-signer

I'm trying to deploy a simple smart contract to my playground on parity/Etherium. I finally managed to run authority and member nodes and I have written code that calls smart contract method. However, when I run it I always get subj error.

I have given 10 billions of ethereum to the account, I'm able to perform actions from Parity UI, but I'm not able to execute this code from application.

My code, for reference:

```
var web3 = new Web3(_ethereumSettings.ParityConnectionString);
var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(_ethereumSettings.FactoryAbi, _ethereumSettings.FactoryContractAddress);
var getAddressFunction = contract.GetFunction("newEntity");
object guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray();
await getAddressFunction.SendTransactionAndWaitForReceiptAsync(_ethereumSettings.AccountAddress,
                                                               functionInput: new[]
                                                                   {guid});
```

What's wrong? I just want to use blockchain as storage for all my transaction so I have to make this account have unlimited access to everything, but I'm stuch with "queue limit is full", even when there is almost no pending transactions in my playground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I figured out that all transaction should be called with specific user or they don't pass:

```
var web3 = new Web3(
   new ManagedAccount(_ethereumSettings.AccountAddress, _ethereumSettings.AccountPassword),
   _ethereumSettings.ParityConnectionString
);
```

Solves the problem if account have enough ether.